# Unable to create an Azure subscription for a dev Azure AD

Tags: azure

I have created a new Dev Azure AD in Azure , When i switch Directories to this new AD, i am unable to create a subscription under the Dev AD Tenant, The Error message is;

"You don't have permission to create a subscription for this billing account, contact the billing account owners."

I have worked with the Billing accountenter image description here owner to verify i have all the required permissions, still yet i can't create this resource. Am an owner on the Dev AD Tenant, can there be any other reason why am unable to create this resource?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue.  I'm a Global Admin in a newly created tenant, and a member/owner of the Billing and Enrollment account I've selected -- but the UI shows me the same error and won't let me proceed.